# No puedo cambiar las propiedades de un JavaBean

Tags: java, java-swing, eclipse, windowbuilder

Estoy trabajando con el IDE Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) y con Java 13.0.1.
Todo actualizado y funcionando perfectamente. También tengo instalado el plug-in WindowBuilder PRO para los componentes visuales.
Y estoy haciendo desarrollos para escritorio, es decir, Java SE.

Acabo de hacer un `javabean` muy simple. Un botón con algunas características personalizadas como color de fondo y color de texto, el texto a mostrar y la fuente para ese texto. Realmente MUY SIMPLE.
Todo tienen sus getters y setters y tengo un constructor vacío.
También implementé la interfaz `Serializable`
Genero el JAR correspondiente.
Retoco el `MANIFEST.MF` (ya que el Eclipse parece no hacerlo automáticamente) y lo agrego a una paleta de componentes personalizados para poder seleccionarlo como cualquier otro componente.
Hasta ahí todo perfecto.
Lo selecciono de la paleta para agregarlo en un panel, y en el panel de propiedades no puedo acceder a ninguna de las propiedades del componente.
Las muestra, pero no puedo cambiarlas. Me muestra todas las propiedades de los JButton (la clase que extiende) y las propiedades personalizadas que yo agregué. Pero en cada caso me pone un combobox vacío.
Para los colores debería traerme un colorchooser y para el Font algo con qué seleccionar el font.
Pero no muestra nada más que un combobox vacío.
A continuación les muestro el código de mi botón:

```
package com.ar.imia.custom.buttons;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class BotonBasico extends JButton implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Color       colorFondo=new Color (0, 0, 255);
    private Color       colorTexto=new Color (255, 255, 255);
    private Font        fuenteTexto=new Font ("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 10); 
    private String      texto="New Button";


    public BotonBasico () {
        super ();
        inicializar ();
    }

    protected void inicializar () {
        this.setFont (fuenteTexto);
        this.setText (texto);
        this.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        this.setBorder(null);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (200, 40));
        this.setBackground(colorFondo);
        this.setForeground(colorTexto);
    }

    public Color getColorFondo() {
        return colorFondo;
    }


    public void setColorFondo(Color colorFondo) {
        this.colorFondo = colorFondo;
    }


    public Color getColorTexto() {
        return colorTexto;
    }


    public void setColorTexto(Color colorTexto) {
        this.colorTexto = colorTexto;
    }


    public Font getFuenteTexto() {
        return fuenteTexto;
    }


    public void setFuenteTexto(Font fuenteTexto) {
        this.fuenteTexto = fuenteTexto;
    }


    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }


    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

}
```

Así queda el Manifest dentro del JAR:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Name: com/ar/imia/custom/buttons/BotonBasico.class
Java-Bean: True
```

Y así se ven las propiedades
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede orientarme por dónde mirar, se los agradecería.
Saludos !!

Comment: Te aconsejo agregar código de lo que comentas así una captura de lo que se mira de forma incorrecta. Eso ayudará a que alguien se de más ideas de tu problema.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro !! Ya edité la pregunta y agregué el código y una imagen para aclarar la pregunta. Muchas gracias por el consejo. Saludos !!

Comment: podrias agregar tu manifest para verificar que este como debe?